# Probability: tossing an unfair coin

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A coin lands on heads at a probability $p\in\left(0,\frac12\right)\cup\left(\frac12,1\right)$ when tossed. We continue to toss the coin until we get **head-head-head** or **head-tail-head** in a row. Find the probability of ending at **head-head-head**.

I assumed that the probability that the last two tosses

- are head-head but we don't stop is $A_n$.
- are tail-head but we don't stop is $B_n$.
- are tail-tail but we don't stop is $C_n$.
- are head-tail but we don't stop is $D_n$.

We have $n\ge3$,
\begin{cases}A_n=pB_{n-1},&(1)\\\\B_n=pC_{n-1},&(2)\\\\C_n=(1-p)C_{n-1}+(1-p)D_{n-1},&(3)\\\\D_n=(1-p)A_{n-1}+(1-p)B_{n-1}.&(4)\end{cases}

I now have a solution, but the method differs from lulu's:

Plug $(1)\to(4)$, $(2)\to(3)$,
\begin{cases}
D_n=(1-p)B_{n-1}+p(1-p)B_{n-2},\\[1em]\frac1pB_{n+1}=(1-p)D_{n-1}+\frac{1-p}pB_n.
\end{cases}
Hence, for $n\ge5$,
\[B_{n+1}=(1-p)B_n+p(1-p)^2B_{n-2}+p^2(1-p)^2B_{n-3}.\]
Now consider
\[\sum_{n\ge5}B_{n+1}\!=\!(1-p)\sum_{n\ge5}B_n\!+\!p(1-p)^2\sum_{n\ge5}B_{n-2}\!+\!p^2(1-p)^2\sum_{n\ge5}B_{n-3}.\]
Let $s=\sum\limits_{n\ge2}B_n$. Now
\begin{align}s\!-\!B_2\!-\!B_3\!-\!B_4\!-\!B_5=\begin{aligned}s(1-p)\!-\!(B_2+B_3+B_4)(1-p)\\\\+sp(1-p)^2\!-\!B_2~p(1-p)^2\!+\!sp^2(1-p)^2.\end{aligned}\tag5\end{align}
Since
\[B_2=p-p^2,~B_3=p+p^3-2p^2,~B_4=p-2p^2+p^3,\]
Solving $(5)$ gives
\[\sum_{n\ge2}B_n=s=\frac{1+p^4-p^3-p^3}{p+p^2-p^3}.\]
So
\[\mathrm P(\text{HHH})=p\sum_{n\ge2}A_n=pA_2+p^2\sum_{n\ge2}B_n=\boxed{\frac{p}{p+1-p^2}}.\]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it with states, labeling states according to how much of a useful string we have built.   As active states we have the starting state, $S_0$ (in which we aren't in one signficant string or another) and we have the state $S_H$ (where the last meaningful toss was $H$), $S_{HH}$, $S_{HT}$.  Note that $S_T,S_{TT}$ are the same as $S_0$  Let $P_X$ be the probability of winning (i.e. ending in $HHH$) if you are in state $S_X$ (so the answer we want is $P_0$).

For example, $P_0=P_H$ since any initial run of $T's$ is irrelevant and we will eventually get to an $H$ (unless $p=0$, in which case there is no end to the game).

Then $$P_0=pP_H+(1-p)P_0\quad P_H=pP_{HH}+(1-p)P_{HT}$$ $$ P_{HT}=p\times 0+(1-p)P_0\quad P_{HH}=p\times 1 +(1-p)P_{HT}$$

All of which implies that $$P_0=\frac p{-p^2+p+1}$$

Note that of course the system degenerates if $p=0$.

Also:  I strongly suggest checking the algebra, I did it quickly.  As a cheap sanity check, taking $p=1$ gives $P_0=1$ as it should. As another sanity check, this expression runs from $0$ to $1$ as $p$ does.

Comment: Which tosses are "meaningless" do you mean?

Comment: Anything that doesn't add to a string.  If, say, the string was $TTHHTTH$ we'd be in $S_H$.  The point of the states is to record how much of a useful string we have built (if any).

Comment: I note that [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+x%3Dp*z%2B%281-p%29*w%2C+w%3D%281-p%29*x%2C+z%3Dp%2B%281-p%29w+for+x%2C+z%2C+w) agrees with my solution (which of course assumes that my recursions are accurate, but at least it checks the solution algebra).

Comment: The idea here:  don't try to look at all the possible strings, that's a mess.  In any situation, which hasn't ended yet, there is really only a small number of game states we might find ourselves in.  These recur (in the same way the strings recur) and we can get a linear system out of that.

Comment: I felt a bit perplexed again when I recollected this solution, so would you mind explaining a bit more? My question is: why would the equations like $P_0=pP_H+(1-p)P_0$ hold regardless of how many times we have operated?

Comment: Say you are in $S_0$. That might mean you were just starting, or that the last few tosses were unhelpful.  For example $HHTTTHTT$ ends  in $S_0$.  From that state, you either throw $H$ (prob. $p$) which moves you to $S_H$ or you throw a $T$ (prob $1-p$) which leaves you in $S_0$.

Comment: It might help if you draw a picture.  Put a bunch of circles on the paper and label them by the states.  Now draw arrows between them according to where you move if you next toss $H$ or $T$.

Comment: Also:  you should convince yourself directly that $P_0=P_H$.  After all, every completed game must go through $S_H$.  The only way to avoid that state is to throw only $T's$ forever.

Comment: Hi again… Would this method work if were asked to find the expected value of steps before the coin stops getting tossed?

Comment: Sure. For each state assign a variable for the expected number of steps,  then use the transitions to get a linear system you can solve